# how to remove the object that meets the condition from an array of objects?

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular7, splice, arrayobject

I receive in my function an object with the following information

```
{
  "name": "Grand modèle",
  "description": "Par 10",
  "price": 0,
  "functional_id": "grand_modele_par_10",
  "quantity": 2,
  "amount": 0
}
```

and I need to check on the next array of objects in which it is positioned to remove it

```
[
  {
    "name": "Matériel crémation",
    "products": [
      {
        "file": "data:image/;base64,",
        "name": "Sacs bordeaux",
        "description": "Pour les crémations Référence",
        "id": 12,
        "path": "",
        "items": [
          {
            "name": "Petit modèle",
            "description": "Par 25",
            "price": 0,
            "functional_id": "petit_modele_par_25",
            "quantity": 2,
            "amount": 0
          },
          {
            "name": "Grand modèle",
            "description": "Par 10",
            "price": 0,
            "functional_id": "grand_modele_par_10",
            "quantity": 2,
            "amount": 0,
            "itemAdded": false
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "Documents",
    "products": [
      {
        "file": "data:image/;base64,",
        "name": "Affiches procédure",
        "description": "De prise en charge",
        "id": 18,
        "path": "",
        "items": [
          {
            "price": 0,
            "functional_id": "affiches_procedure",
            "quantity": 1,
            "amount": 0
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

To do this I go through the array of objects with a 'forEach' to locate the item that meets the condition of being equal and remove it

```
public deleteItem(item) {


        this.fullCartInfo.forEach(category => {
            category.products.forEach(product => {
                product.items.forEach(itemAdded => {
                    if (item.functional_id === itemAdded.functional_id) {
                        this.fullCartInfo.splice(itemAdded);
                    }
                });
            });
        });
        this.cartService.removeItem(item);
    }
```

what I get is for him to empty my array of objects. How can I get him to delete only the one who meets the condition?
What's my mistake?
Thank you all for your time

Comment: [`Array.prototype.splice(start[, deleteCount[, item1[, item2[, ...]]]])`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice): _"`start`: The index at which to start changing the array. `deleteCount`: An integer indicating the number of elements in the array to remove from start."_

Comment: thank you very much @Andreas  I've only been programming for a short time and sometimes I get stuck on very obvious things

Comment: I've edited my answer. Have a look at the part below the first snippet. Your `.splice()` approach can have unwanted side effects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Array.prototype.splice(start[, deleteCount[, item1[, item2[, ...]]]])`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) expects the index of the first element that should be removed (`start`) and optionally how many elements should be removed (`deleteCount`).

For the `start` index we can use the second argument of the [`Array.prototype.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) callback which is the index of the current element in the collection.

The following example uses:

- a reduced set of data
- a regular function instead of your class method, just because it was easier to work with. You can just copy&paste the body of the function into your `deleteItem` method.

```js
const objectToRemove = { "functional_id": "grand_modele_par_10" }

const objects = {
  fullCartInfo: [
    { "products": [{ "id": 12, "items": [{ "functional_id": "grand_modele_par_10" }] }] },
    { "products": [{ "id": 18, "items": [{ "functional_id": "affiches_procedure" }] }] }
  ]
}

function deleteItem(item) {
  this.fullCartInfo.forEach((category, index) => {  // the index we will use for .splice() when we've found a matching category
    category.products.forEach(product => {
      product.items.forEach(itemAdded => {
        if (item.functional_id === itemAdded.functional_id) {
          this.fullCartInfo.splice(index, 1);  // remove one item only
        }
      });
    });
  });
}

deleteItem.apply(objects, [objectToRemove]);
// .apply() is only used to set the value of <this> in deleteItem and therefor simulate its behavior as a class method.

console.log(objects);
```

But this will only work when you only remove one item from the collection, or if you remove the items from the end. Otherwise the index of `.fullCartInfo.forEach(...)` will be out of sync with the actual collection that you've just modified with `.splice()`.
E.g. you remove the first item at index `0`, the array then will shift all elements one index to the left (item at index 1 would then be at index 0, item at index 2 would then be at index 1, ...) but the index in the callback won't be updated.

If there's a chance that you will remove multiple items then you should use `.filter()` or a good old `for` loop which iterates from the last to the first item.

`.filter()`

```js
const objectToRemove = { "functional_id": "grand_modele_par_10" }

const objects = {
  fullCartInfo: [
    { "products": [{ "id": 12, "items": [{ "functional_id": "grand_modele_par_10" }] }] },
    { "products": [{ "id": 18, "items": [{ "functional_id": "affiches_procedure" }] }] }
  ]
}

function deleteItem(item) {
  this.fullCartInfo = this.fullCartInfo.filter((category, index) => {
    let keepCategory = true;
    
    category.products.forEach(product => {
      product.items.forEach(itemAdded => {
        if (item.functional_id === itemAdded.functional_id) {
          keepCategory = false;
        }
      });
    });
    
    return keepCategory;
  });
}

deleteItem.apply(objects, [objectToRemove]);
console.log(objects);
```

`for` loop in reverse

```js
const objectToRemove = { "functional_id": "grand_modele_par_10" }

const objects = {
  fullCartInfo: [
    { "products": [{ "id": 12, "items": [{ "functional_id": "grand_modele_par_10" }] }] },
    { "products": [{ "id": 18, "items": [{ "functional_id": "affiches_procedure" }] }] }
  ]
}

function deleteItem(item) {
  for(let index = this.fullCartInfo.length - 1; index >= 0; index--) {
    this.fullCartInfo[index].products.forEach(product => {
      product.items.forEach(itemAdded => {
        if (item.functional_id === itemAdded.functional_id) {
          this.fullCartInfo.splice(index, 1);
        }
      });
    });
  }
}

deleteItem.apply(objects, [objectToRemove]);

console.log(objects);
```